# jqGrid error - "Element is not a table"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

It seems simple enough but I get this cryptic error from the jqGrid code saying "Element is not a table".  Here's the code:

```
var grid_data = [ {id:"1",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"}, {id:"1",invdate:"2010-05-24",name:"test",note:"note",tax:"10.00",total:"2111.00"} , {id:"2",invdate:"2010-05-25",name:"test2",note:"note2",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"}, {id:"3",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"}, {id:"4",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"}, {id:"5",invdate:"2007-10-05",name:"test2",note:"note2",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"}, {id:"6",invdate:"2007-09-06",name:"test3",note:"note3",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"}, {id:"7",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"}, {id:"8",invdate:"2007-10-03",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"21.00",total:"320.00"}, {id:"9",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"}, {id:"11",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"}, {id:"12",invdate:"2007-10-02",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"}, {id:"13",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"}, {id:"14",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"}, {id:"15",invdate:"2007-10-05",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"}, {id:"16",invdate:"2007-09-06",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"}, {id:"17",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"}, {id:"18",invdate:"2007-10-03",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"}, {id:"19",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"}, {id:"21",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"}, {id:"22",invdate:"2007-10-02",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"}, {id:"23",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"}, {id:"24",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"}, {id:"25",invdate:"2007-10-05",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"}, {id:"26",invdate:"2007-09-06",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"}, {id:"27",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"}, {id:"28",invdate:"2007-10-03",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"}, {id:"29",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"}  ]; 
var default_grid = {
            datatype: "local", 
            height: 80, 
            rowNum: 10, 
            rowList: [10,20,30], 
            multiselect: true, 
            rowList:[10,20,30], 
            sortname: 'id', viewrecords: true, sortorder: "asc",
            footerrow: true,
            loadui: "block"
};
var grid_detail = $.extend({ 
    data: grid_data, 
    colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Client', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'], 
    colModel:[ 
        {name:'id',index:'id', width:60, sorttype:"int"}, {name:'invdate',index:'invdate', width:90, sorttype:"date", formatter:"date"},
        {name:'name',index:'name', width:100}, {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float", formatter:"number"}, 
        {name:'tax',index:'tax', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float"}, {name:'total',index:'total', width:80,align:"right",sorttype:"float"},
        {name:'note',index:'note', width:150, sortable:false}
    ],
    caption: "Test Grid" ,
    pager: '#plist2'
},default_grid);

$('#abutton').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('<div></div>').dialog().jqGrid(grid_detail);
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not a cryptic message at all.  The element is not a table, meaning the element you're trying to turn into a grid is not a table.  This makes good sense: you're using a div:

```
$('<div></div>')
```

So instead of doing it all in javascript, just make the following HTML:

```
<div id="myDialog"><table id="myGrid"></table></div>
```

and then make your dialog and grid:

```
$('#myDialog').dialog();
$('#myGrid').jqGrid ...
```

**EDIT**: to do this completely dynamically:

```
$('<div><table></table></div>').dialog().find('table:first').jqGrid(...);
```

Comment: I see now.  The reason for all JS is because the project I'm working will require arbitrary jqGrids to be made off data sent to the front end.  So putting it (div+table) into HTML is ok for testing only.  With that said, how might you do it dynamically?

Comment: @Brandon Minton: You can easy change the code which Milimetric suggest to make it "more dynamically". The code `var container = $("body"), dlg = container.append('<div"></div>').find('div:last'), grid = dlg.append('<table id="myGrid"></table>').find('#myGrid'); dlg.dialog(); grid.jqGrid({/*all jqGrid parameters*/});` is dynamic. You should only understand, that the `<table>` element **have to** have `id` attribute (unique on the page).

Comment: Oleg, thanks for your help!  This is really useful information.  It seems in my code that as you said the table must be unique but also the parent container element doesn't seem to work without being unique either.  Have you noticed this as well?